# iOS, disable push notifications without changing profile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I recently setup push notifications in my app with parse. 
I updated my adhoc profile, p12 etc.

However I've decided I want wait till my next release before I provide push notifications.

I commented out the parse import and code.
However when I run my app on a new device the accept push notifications message is still shown.

I really don't want to modify my profile etc.

What do I need to do?

UPDATED:
I'd forgotten to also remove registerForRemoteNotificationTypes, however I've never uploaded my app to the app store yet, I'm using test flight. How can I test to ensure this works, aka reset a device. As mentioned I've deleted the device from parse and didn't get the permission message on my device when I tested this?

Comment: Just go on parse server and delete the ck.pem file or certificate which you have uploaded on Parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to disable the push notifications alert you need to upload new build on the app store where you will comment the code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)]
```

Now. Whenever you app runs will not ask user for permission and hence will not receive any alert.

Disabling of deleting the ck.pem file on the parse server will not send any notification to the devices on which you app is installed. But these devices will ask for the user permission to receive push notifications.

Hope this will help you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: I'd forgotten to also remove registerForRemoteNotificationTypes, however I've never uploaded my app to the app store yet, I'm using test flight. How can I test to ensure this works, aka reset a device. As mentioned I've deleted the device from parse and didn't get the permission message on my device when I tested this?

Comment: if your app is on development than you just need to create a new build and commenting the registerForRemoteNotificationTypes code.

Comment: Ok, but why can't I test this? Why won't deleting the device I'd from parse cause the permission message?